# Dispose MemoryStream in Async Callback function

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, amazon-s3, memorystream

I am using AWS S3 Async upload function to upload a file to S3.

```
tu.BeginUpload(ur, new AsyncCallback(FinishedAsyncUpload),ms);
```

**ms** = Memory Stream

**tu.InputStream** = ms

My problem is that I want to dispose the Stream after the file has been uploaded. I create a callback function called `FinishedAsyncUpload`. I also pass the MemoryStream (ms) and dispose it in this function.

```
 protected void FinishedAsyncUpload(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ((MemoryStream)result.AsyncState).Dispose();
    }
```

My problem is that when I try to dispose the memory stream in the callback function,  I see that the object doesn't contain any data and asking for length throws (`System.objectDisposedException`).

How can I dispose the memoryStream after the file has been uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am admittedly not familiar with the AWS API specifically, but typically System.ObjectDisposedException is only thrown when `Dispose()` is called on an already-disposed object.  So it may be that the AWS API is disposing of the processed stream for you.

[From MSDN for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ObjectDisposedException Class
>
> The exception that is thrown when an operation is performed on a disposed object.